# Is Stack Apps site part of The Stack Overflow Trilogy?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

Is the Stack Apps site part of The Stack Overflow Trilogy, or is it just one site of the <strike>Stack Overflow family sites</strike> Stack Exchange sites?
Sorry, but I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the Stack Overflow family sites and the Stack Overflow Trilogy were separate entities. Now *I* am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Apps support site is, essentially, a Stack Exchange site. It runs on the Stack Exchange engine. It provides Q&A for a community for product support, feature requests, and bug reporting.

The topic just *happens* to be a product of the Stack Overflow developers. But there's nothing to tie it *specifically or exclusively* to the Trilogy.

Comment: It's in the footer of the trilogy sites, so I'd say it's at least in the League of Justice.

Comment: You can also associate your SO, SU, SF and Meta accounts so it's definitely part of the increasingly inaccurately named trilogy.

Comment: @Robert I'm still confused about this naming.

Comment: @systempuntoout - Yes, all very confusing with the historical names being redefined and legally changed. I plan to blog about it once I get past this SE 2.0 beta craziness: http://blog.stackexchange.com/post/628155535/interview-with-lead-developer-david-fullerton

Comment: @ChrisF - But accounts also associate with Careers, the Stack Exchange Proposal site, and *every* site in the new Stack Exchange network. So, clearly the "Trilogy" refers to the four sites of the original service (SO, SF, meta, and SU).

Comment: The meaning of "Trilogy" depends on the time it was written. Originally, it was just the three sites SO, SF and MSO. Then, SU launched, and was added. Then more sites launched... I've updated [the glossary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's an essential element of the StackOverflow Quintology.

Comment: I'd say it's more like a Trilogy. In the Douglas Adams sense of the word, that is. :)