# How should we refer to the “trilogy” + StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, terminology

Crossposted from StackApps as per a request in there.

I'm currently designing an app for the StackApps beta. One of the challenges I found when writing descriptions and user-facing material for my app is how to refer to the "trilogy" + StackExchange.

Are Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault part of StackExchange, or are they separate?

If they are separate, is there a better term than "the trilogy" (which is probably incomprehensible to people not as familiar with the site), and what should we call the combination of them and Stack Overflow?

Comment: Looking at Robert's final comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51504/is-stack-apps-site-part-of-the-stack-overflow-trilogy/51518#51518) makes me consider that "Trilogy" will basically refer to the original 4 sites as a significant unit, even if everything will be part of one big Stack Exchange Network. So I think distinguishing the "trilogy" will probably only be necessary when you need to point at those sites in specific.

Comment: So does that mean that "Stack Exchange" includes the trilogy? Basically, if I'm trying to say "this app works with StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser, and whatever StackExchange sites may be added", can I can just say "this works with StackExchange sites"?

Comment: Looking through all of the announcements, there's a lot of mention that the trilogy will soon be moved to the same code base as the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites. So I imagine that any app that works with SE2.0 will work with the trilogy, and vice versa. However, I can't find any concrete statement of whether the sites of the trilogy will be considered part of the Stack Exchange Network in name.

Comment: Oh, here it is. [David Fullerton](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52026/why-do-we-ask-area-51-questions-here-meta-stackoverflow-rather-than-on-meta-sta/52035#52035) states that the trilogy will basically be the "founders" of the Stack Exchange Network. So you should be perfectly fine to state "this works with Stack Exchange sites".

Comment: Stack Stuff? __

Answer (score 4):

See the full usage document linked from the [legal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal) link in the footer:

[**Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

The excerpt (below) is a little more rigidly formal than using (unofficial) terms like "[the Trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50912/what-is-the-correct-name-to-use-when-referencing-the-trilogy-sites/50931#50931)" but this is how the name use is described under...

> **Stack Overflow Internet Services Inc.** is the official name of the company, but you are welcome to say Stack Overflow Inc. to disambiguate between the site for programmers and the company.
>
> **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.
>
> A **Stack Exchange site** is a Q&A website built on the technology of Stack Overflow Inc. The phrase "Stack Exchange" is generally used as an adjective, not a noun. One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51" (wrong).
>
> The **Stack Exchange Network** refers to the collection of Stack Exchange sites and services.
>
> **Area 51** (two words) is the site used to propose new Stack Exchange sites for the Stack Exchange Network.
>
> The **Stack Exchange API** allows users to write applications based on the Stack Exchange engine. The API is always referred to as "Stack Exchange API", even if the application is written for a specific site (i.e. never Stack Overflow API, Server Fault API, etc.).
>
> The **Stack Overflow Blog** is the company blog which talks about everything we're doing on all our sites and what the company itself is doing.

Comment: Does this mean the occasional "Stack Overflow LLC" I see now and then is outdated/incorrect?

Comment: @ccomet: Yes, completely incorrect. It no longer exists, legally and otherwise.

Comment: It's "Area 51" but [area51].  The discrepancy will keep prompting users to say Area51.  Should the tag be renamed to [area-51]?

Comment: @TheCat I imagine the tag can remain [area51], just like we keep [stackoverflow]. This may have been discussed, though, and if not, it may even be a good topic of a discussion.

Comment: I suppose we still have users that say StackOverflow, but we manage, somehow. @cco

Comment: [area-51] seems a bit pedantic. No one will remember and we'll end up with two tags. Maybe when we have tag synonyms.

Comment: @Robert, we should put this as a link in the FAQ

Comment: `[area-51]` is considered a synonym of the master tag `[area51]`, as of 3 Oct 2010: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/area51/synonyms

Answer (score 2):

It is simply the Stack Exchange Network now.  Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User were the first members.

[From another meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52026/why-do-we-ask-area-51-questions-here-meta-stackoverflow-rather-than-on-meta-sta/52035#52035):

> Stack Exchange is no longer a separate product: it's now the name for the entire network, of which Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User are the founding members.

Answer (score 0):

I propose we colloquially refer to them as "[Overflow Flavored](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45596/let-me-post-as-many-links-as-long-as-they-are-overflow-flavored-closed)" sites.