# How can I see the list of my comments?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of Comments on User Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2586/list-of-comments-on-user-tab)

In compliance with massive requests I passed to write  comments only

I cannot find anywhere the list of my comments made.

How can I see the list of my comments and order them by time?

Comment: No reason for a downvote here, that's a justified and good question...despite the user who's asking it.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can view your most recent comments in the Activity tab in your user profile. Depending on how much you post, this may or may not be sufficient.

The only way (at the moment) to get a listing of *all* your comments is to run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/93/my-comments) on Data Explorer. The default sorting is descending by score, but you can easily change it to sort by date, or add a criterion to do a text search, etc. This method is complete, however the data dumps are only once/month, so you may have to wait for the most recent ones that are no longer in your recent activity.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your account page, `Activity` tab.

Comment: But you only get to see the latest ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is no list of comments. For a while they are in the `activity` tab of your user profile, but other than that there is no place to find them. There you can't sort them or anything.

Comments are not a main focus in a Q&A site, therefore there is no additional handling for them.

Comment: Can you pass this message to @jinguy that I had written comments to my question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61383/when-can-i-start-editing-to-know-it-is-not-a-waste-of-time  explaining that I could not  attend his invitation? I asked his (of @jinguy) Email address in my Email msg to moderator Benjamin Dumke (who closed this my account) but this moderator is not responding

Comment: My comments there are in comments body to my main question, and they appear as written by @Anonymous

Comment: @vgv8 I am sure that jinguy saw all your comments. Please don't abuse comments to stay on line and still be able to use your suspended accounts. by the way, there are tons of new users that have no problems in all SE sites - don't blame the community for your suspension.